# G is a group of order n, n is finite, and any two distinct subgroups of G have different orders, want to prove that G is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

G is a group of order n, n is finite,
 and any two distinct subgroups of G have different orders,
 want to prove that G is cyclic.

Comment: As stated, this isn't true. Consider the group of symmetries of the triangle. There are subgroups of orders 2 and 3, but the group is certainly not cyclic. Is the question written correctly? Also, what have you tried; where are you stuck?

Comment: @Josh B.  I think the OP means that any two distinct subgroups of $G$ have different orders.

Comment: @JoshB. I think the intention here was that **any** two *different* subgroups of $\;G\;$ have different orders.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

(**) We're in fact given that the equation $\;x^d=1\;$, for $\;d\mid n\;$ , has at most $\;d\;$ solutions in $\;G\;$ (why?)

(**) If $\;\varphi\;$ is Euler's Totient Function, we have that

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)=n$$

(**) From both points above it follows that there *must* be an element in $\;G\;$ of order $\;n\;$ ...